# How to add weblogic maven dependency?

Tags: maven

When I add dependency I get following error :

> [ERROR] Plugin com.oracle.weblogic:weblogic-maven-plugin:10.3.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.oracle.weblogic:weblogic-maven-plugin:jar:10.3.6 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
>
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>
> [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException

Comment: try to run your maven command with -U flag, to force an update. If that doesn't help please provide us with more information about your pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to define an extra repository in your `~/.m2/settings.xml` file, or add an extra proxy repository to your artifact repository (e.g. Nexus).

It seems that getting access to that repository is somewhat involved, so I'll just point you to what would seem to be the right documentation:

https://blogs.oracle.com/WebLogicServer/entry/weblogic_server_and_the_oracle

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I have done changes but this time i will get different exception.[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:weblogic-maven-plugin:2.9.5:deploy (default-cli) on project jiowifi_captive_v3.0: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:weblogic-maven-plugin:2.9.5:deploy failed: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:weblogic-maven-plugin:2.9.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: weblogic:weblogic:jar:10.3.6, weblogic:webservices:jar:10.3.6: Could not find artifact weblogic:weblogic:jar:10.3.6 in central

Answer (score 0):

The error implies that the plugin was not available in the plugin repository.

Please modify your pom to include the plugin as:

```
<build> 
<plugins> 
 <plugin> 
  <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId> 
  <artifactId>weblogic-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
  <version>10.3.4</version> 
  <configuration> 
      <adminurl>t3://localhost:7001</adminurl>
      <user>weblogic</user> 
      <password>weblogic123</password> 
      <upload>true</upload> 
      <action>deploy</action> 
      <remote>false</remote> 
      <verbose>true</verbose> 
        <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</source> 
     <name>${project.build.finalName}</name> 
  </configuration> 
  </plugin>  
</plugins>
</build>
```

Please change `adminurl`, `user`, `password` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I have done changes but this time i will get different exception.[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:weblogic-maven-plugin:2.9.5:deploy (default-cli) on project jiowifi_captive_v3.0: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:weblogic-maven-plugin:2.9.5:deploy failed: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:weblogic-maven-plugin:2.9.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: weblogic:weblogic:jar:10.3.6, weblogic:webservices:jar:10.3.6: Could not find artifact weblogic:weblogic:jar:10.3.6 in central